# Complete list of UK postcodes plus their city, county, uk country

Tags: data, united-kingdom, reverse-geocoding, postal-code

Is there a free data set of all current UK postcodes (about 1.7 million-ish) plus their city name, county and UK country (e.g. Liverpool, Merseyside, England) and ideally lat, long, east, northings?

Comment: This looks like a question that is highly on-topic for [opendata.se] Stack Exchange and problematic here because there are no spatial fields mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[OS Code-Point Open](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html) is probably the best you will get for free, and should provide you with all the data you need.

Comment: Thanks. I came across this in the past and played with it again today. Unfortunately, I cannot find a complete csv or something similar.

Comment: It seems to point to many different data sets. Is there one in particular which contains all the data?

Comment: The OS site is not the most well designed... Once you click through to the download section from the link I provided, Code-Point Open is about half way down the page. You tick the download box, then go right to the bottom of the page and click next to continue.

Comment: Ok thanks that helped. However, county info in Admin_county_code seems not complete.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [National Statistics Postcode Lookup](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/7ec10db7-c8f4-4a40-8d82-8921935b4865/national-statistics-postcode-lookup-uk). It seems to be the official source.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Way easier to use than some of the other answers.  Does exactly what I want... one easy to use csv to match postcodes to county/country/etc.

Answer (score 2):

[OS Open Names](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-names.html) might be a better option as it has postcode, populated place (could be a city, town, village etc), unitary county, and country.

Note that these fields will not always be what you might expect though, especially unitary county.

Here is an example for postcode RG4 7LR:

- **POPULATED_PLACE:** Caversham
- **COUNTY_UNITARY:** Reading
- **COUNTRY:** England